# Android SQL database Load data from specific table

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating one table when application launches and adding more tables from EditText String names.

My First Database table

```
public static final String CREATE_ERAMPE_TABLE = "create table details" +
        "(id integer primary key, username text, metre text, northing double," +
        "eastings double,identification text, phone text, date text)";
```

Creating additional tables from activity by

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    newTableName = dbTableName.getText().toString();
    String sql = "create table "+ newTableName+
            "(id integer primary key, username text, metre text, northing text," +
            "eastings text,identification text, phone text, date text)";
    Log.i("CreateDb=", sql);
```

when inserting data to specific

```
  String insertTo = metreUsers.getTableName();

    return database.insert(insertTo, null, cvs);
```

getting list of all tablenames into a listview i use the following code

```
 public ArrayList<RegisteredGroups> getRegisteredGroups(){
    ArrayList<RegisteredGroups> arrTblnames = new ArrayList<RegisteredGroups>();
   // database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence'", null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        RegisteredGroups grp = new RegisteredGroups();
        grp.setGroupName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        arrTblnames.add(grp);
        //get count of entries in every single table
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int cnt = cursor.getCount();
        grp.setGroupNumber(String.valueOf(cnt));
    }
```

now from here when i click on the first item on the listView which contains a database table name i want to load data from that specific table in to a listview.

to pass the table name am using

```
rgGroup = (RegisteredGroups)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if (rgGroup != null){
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        FragmentManager frag = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = frag.beginTransaction();
        arguments.putParcelable("selectedGroup", rgGroup);
        RegisteredUsersList regs = new RegisteredUsersList();
        regs.setArguments(arguments);
```

Comment: you mean you have to get data from selected table name, right??

Comment: FSM save us! why are you creating new table for new user ?  instead create two tables `users` and `details` in `details` table add foreign key to table `users` ...

Comment: yes..i want to get data from the selected table and show it on a listview;

Comment: its simple, just pass table name from selected listview item and get all data from database.

Comment: Take it like this.. i have 5 groups.. every group has 50-100 users. every is accountable for everything concerning its members.pricing,varience in reading etc

Comment: @Aetukamz : So whats the issue ???

Comment: in your OnItemClickListener of adapter get the selected tablename and get the data for that tablename like "select * from "+selectedname thats all right ???

Comment: i've tried this using parcelable to pass the table name but instead am always getting data from the first table name.

Comment: add log and check is table name is right? you are passing to database or your new table is create or not??

Comment: am able to create tables, but am getting an error of invalid tables

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> loadArtist(){

    ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database=getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =  database.query(
        ArtistMaster.ArtistDetails.TABLE_NAME,
        new String[] {ArtistMaster.ArtistDetails.COLUMN_ARTIST_NAME},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    );

  while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
      list.add(cursor.getString(
         cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
             ArtistMaster.ArtistDetails.COLUMN_ARTIST_NAME)));
  }

  return list;

}
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer :)